# How to find the path in a floor plan image using java? Help me on how to implement diijistrak or A star algorithm for this

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am new to the image processing discipline, currently I am working on an activity to find the path in a given floor plan image using java. I could understand & implement a plain Dijkstra or A star algorithm in java to find the shortest path between nodes that can work on hard coded values for nodes & edges. But I have no idea on how to do the same with image file as input. 
I could not find any much detailed or comprehensive solution for this on web surfing. Any idea on how to achieve this. Kindly help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the walls on your plan are black, and the space is white, then use the white pixels as the space in which you can search using your algorithms.

be aware that:

- The plan images could need some preprocessing, like adjusting brightness/contrast and/or converting into lower resolution picture.

If the plans are more complicated than that, ie. you need to take into account some special signs or structures on them then you need to do more complicated conversion/preprocessing and/or image recognition, using some special tools, maybe even some AI.

Comment: Thanks for your info. But I am much concerned about on how to implement A star algorithm on a floor plan image(input to the algorithm - ie; image to data model conversion. to extract room names, distance between each, etc).  Once I compute the shortest path, it should be re-drawn back to the image file.

Comment: kindly explain downvote?